# A function where absolute maximum is also absolute minimum?

Tags: functions, absolute-value

What is an example of a real-valued function where an absolute maximum is also an absolute minimum?

Comment: A constant one?

Comment: What do you mean by "absolute maximum"? Do you mean a *global* maximum, i.e. an $x$ such that for every $y$ you have $f(x) \geq f(y)$?

Comment: The terms "absolute maximum" and "global maximum" are synonymous as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks, so it is just a constant. I was overthinking this question and wasn't sure if the answer was just trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Suppose that the absolute maximum value is $M$.  By definition this means that $f(x)\le M$ for every value of $x$.  If the same $M$ is the absolute minimum value, this means that. . .

Can you finish this and determine what $f(x)$ is?

Answer (score 3):

$$\large{\large{\large{\large{\large{-}}}}}$$

Comment: (+1): "Brevity is the soul of wit" - Hamlet, act 2, scene 2.

Comment: You should see what I did to circumvent the 50 character minimum..

Comment: V clever.  I guess you could also have done something like this: \overline{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ }

Answer (score 3):

The only functions which have this property are the constant functions.

Why?

Suppose $f(x) \geq f(m)$ for all $x$. Then $x=m$ is the global minimum of $f$. Likewise, if $f(x) \leq f(M)$ for all $x$. Then $x=M$ is the global maximum of $f$. So if $f(M)=f(m)$, we have $f(m) \leq f(x) \leq f(M)=f(m)$ for all $x$. This forces $f(x)=f(m)=f(M)$ for all $x$ so that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is such that $f(a) \leq f(x)$ and $f(x) \leq f(a)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ we have $f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(a)$ which implies $f(a) = f(x)$, that is $f$ is constant.